# Правильно ли добавить все IP из AbuseIPDB в чёрный список?

Tags: ip, ddos, cloudflare

Есть сайт на котором часто бывают DDoS атаки.
Нашёл сегодня сайт AbuseIPDB, и хочу взять через API все самые опасные IP адреса, и добавить их в чёрный список в CloudFlare.

Нормально ли так сделать? Можно доверять AbuseIPDB?

И за одно будет фильтроваться и боты которые находяться в поиске уязвимых сайтов.